# Check for duplicates (random numbers)

Tags: swift, swift2, int, arc4random

In my code I generate six random numbers between 1-5.

```
RandomNumber1 = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
RandomNumber2 = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
RandomNumber3 = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
RandomNumber4 = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
RandomNumber5 = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
RandomNumber6 = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
```

With these numbers, I want to check how many duplicates there are. Two scenarios: I want to execute one code if there are 5 different numbers, and another code if there isn't. Example;

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5
```

Here are 5 different numbers (only one pair)

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4
```

Here are not 5 different numbers (two pairs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Set` and use that to count the unique values:

```
if Set([RandomNumber1,RandomNumber2, RandomNumber3, RandomNumber4, RandomNumber5, RandomNumber6]).count == 5 {
    print("five")
} else {
    print("not five")
}
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work perfectly for me, it executes the code even with only 4 unique values. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Found it out myself, need to ask another question. Thanks ;-)